# How to return acquired SwapChain image back to the SwapChain?

Tags: vulkan

I can currently acquire swap chain image, draw to it and then present it. After vkQueuePresentKHR the image is returned back to the swap chain. Is there other way to return the image back. I do not want to display the rendered data to screen.

Comment: If you do not want to display the rendered image, then why do you use a swapchain anyway. The SC is meant as a tool to present images to the windowing system.

If you do not want to display your result, just create your own attachments (images) not tied to the swapchain and render to them using e.g. a separate render pass.

Comment: @SaschaWillems Just to avoid creating images, allocating memories to it, synchronizing them in round robin fashion for continuous rendering.

Comment: @abhijitjagdale: If you want to avoid doing work, Vulkan is *not* the API for you.

Comment: @NicolBolas I also thought it might affect performance. Will handling images by our self vs swap chain be slower or the same? And since returning of SC images will be handled by system instead of me using fences, I thought SC will be faster.

Comment: @abhijitjagdale Using Images yourself directly you have absolute control — it will be the same or (likely — depending on platform too) faster than Swapchain Images.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably do what you want here by simply not presenting the images to the device.  But the number of images you can get depends on the VkSurfaceCapabilities of your device.

The maximum number of images that the application can simultaneously acquire from this swapchain is derived by subtracting VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::minImageCount from the number of images in the swapchain and adding 1.

On my device, I can have an 8-image swapchain and the minImageCount is 2, letting me acquire 7 images at once.

Comment: But how should I return the images back to the swapchain to reuse it.

Comment: You said you wanted some images to do round-robin continuous rendering, so you don't return the images to the swapchain and handle the round-robin synchronization yourself.  You might do this by using fences to tell when the queue submissions are complete and when it is safe to reuse an image.  By not presenting the image, you are giving up the synchronization provided by the presentation engine that tells you when it is done with the image.  So you'll have to handle that yourself.  As Sascha said, it would make a lot more sense to allocate images yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want for whatever reason to scrap the frame just do not Present the Image and reuse it next iteration (do not Acquire new Image; use the one you already have).

If there's a possibility you are never going to use some Swapchain Image, you still do not need to worry about it. Acquired Images will be reclaimed (unpresented) when a Swapchain is destroyed.

---

Seeing your usage comment now, I must add you still need to synchronize. And it is not guaranteed to be round-robin. And that it sounds very misguided. Creating Swapchain seems like equal programming work to creating and binding memory to the Image. Considering the result is not "how it is meant to be used"...

From a practical point, you will probably not have good choice of Swapchain Image formats, types and usage flags and they can be limited by size and numbers you can use. It will probably not work well across platforms. It may come with performance hit too.

---

TL;DR Swapchains are **only** for interaction with the windowing system (or lack thereof) of the OS. For other uses there are appropriate non-Swapchain commands and objects.

Admittedly Vulkan is sometimes less than terse to write in(a product of it being C-based, reasonably low-level and abstracting a wide range of GPU-like HW), but your proposed technique is not a viable way around it. You need to get used to it and where apropriate make your own abstractions (or use a library doing that).